# Getting TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType

Tags: python, json

My code is:

```
import json
import cozmo
from bitcoinrpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy, JSONRPCException

def getinfo():
 rpc_connection = AuthServiceProxy("http://%s:%s@127.0.0.1:22225"%("user", "pass"))
 print(rpc_connection.getinfo())

data = json.loads(getinfo())
jtopy=json.dumps(data)
dict_json=json.loads(jtopy)

print(dict_json)

#def cozmosay(robot: cozmo.robot.Robot):
#    robot.say_text(getinfo).wait_for_completed()
#
#cozmo.run_program(cozmosay)
```

The code should return "This is a pre-release test build - use at your own risk - do not use for mining or merchant applications" as the full string is `{ "version": 1150100, "protocolversion": 70015, "walletversion": 60000, "balance": 94356667.32563662, "blocks": 133199, "timeoffset": 0, "connections": 4, "proxy": "", "difficulty": 11.30994666912951, "testnet": false, "keypoololdest": 1637356708, "keypoolsize": 692, "paytxfee": 0.00000000, "relayfee": 0.00100000, "errors": "This is a pre-release test build - use at your own risk - do not use for mining or merchant applications" }` but I get this error:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Did you mean: return rpc_connection.getinfo(). ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, getinfo() has no return statement so it returns NoneType.
You should use return instead of print the data only.